# Data returning None in Django with appended Select Field in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a select field with a drop-down list that I append in Javascript. But even though the field is populated, my `clean()` method returns `None`... and so my form doesn't validate etc.

```
class MY_MODEL(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.description or u''

class MY_MODELForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MY_MODEL
        fields = ['date', 'description',]    
        widgets = {
            'description': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'required': False, 'placeholder': 'Description', 'class': 'format-form'}
            ),
            'date': forms.Select(
                attrs={'required': False, 'class': 'format-form'}
            ),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MY_MODELForm, self).clean()
        description = cleaned_data.get("description", None)
        date_worked = cleaned_data.get("date", None)
        #returns None even though populated...
        print date
```

I append a list of dates based off some calcs (Which works fine). I am  using JS for this because the list that is presented is interface dependant. Something like this...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //generate select options
    var dropDownOptions = ["Tuesday 2", "Wednesday 3"]
    var select = $("select[id$='date']")
    for ( j = 0; j < dropDownOptions.length; j++){
        select.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", dropDownOptions[j]).text(dropDownOptions[j]));
    }
 });
```

All the appending and everything works fine... but my `cleaned_data.get('date_worked')` is returning None when something **is selected** something from the drop down....

?
Thanks

Comment: Does the `select` element has `name` attribute set in html? e.g. `<select id="data" name="date">`. Try printing `request.POST` in view to verify if `date` is coming in POST data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` attribute of each option must be a string that can be parsed as a valid date object. By [default this is the list of valid `input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats)

```
['%Y-%m-%d',      # '2006-10-25'
 '%m/%d/%Y',      # '10/25/2006'
 '%m/%d/%y']      # '10/25/06'
```

`"Tuesday 2"` does not match any of the default formats so is being returned as `None`

If you wish to have a custom format you need to set `input_formats` on your `DateField`